# Hybris 2105 CacheAddon not present

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to install cacheaddon in my hybris 2105 storefront but I can't find it anywhere, am I missing something? Do the name changed?

Comment: I've never heard of a cache addon. Do you have any documentation or link when it existed in older versions. I could not find it in 1811.

Comment: I've found it in an old project, I'm starting to think that this addon is custom. Anyways, is there any documentation about how to implement method cache vía XML spring?